# Sets that differ with a Borel set in at most countable points are Borel

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Definet he Borel sigma field on $\mathbb{R}$ by the sigma field generated by right side closed intervals of the form $(a, b]$. I want to show that any set that differs with a Borel set in at most countable points is also Borel. That is, if $$C\Delta B=(C-B)\cup(B-C)$$ is amc and $B \in \mathbb{B(R)}$, then $C \in \mathbb{B(R)}$ also. How should I proceed?

Edit: The trouble is in handling the symmetric difference operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any countable set is Borel (exercise), so it is enough to show that if $B, C$ are Borel, then their difference $B\Delta C$ is again Borel.

To do this, note that $B\Delta C=(B\cap C^c)\cup (C\cap B^c)$. Since Borel sets are closed under complementation, union, and intersection, this is again Borel.

Note that this is more general than what you are asking.

---

EDIT: Hopefully this makes things clearer.

Suppose $A$ differs from a Borel set $B$ by a countable set - that is, $A\Delta B=C$ and $C$ is countable. Then $(A\Delta B)\Delta B=C\Delta B$, but $(A\Delta B)\Delta B=A$ (exercise). So $A=C\Delta B$. But $C\Delta B$ is the symmetric difference of two Borel sets, and hence Borel. So $A$ is Borel.

Comment: That is almost obvious.

Comment: @Iconoclast I've edited to make it clear why this is relevant.

Comment: Yeah but the problem is a bit different, I already know that the symmetric difference is Borel (since it is countable), I want to prove that one of the sets is Borel given that the other is Borel.

Comment: @Iconoclast I'm a little confused: what exactly are you asking? If $B$ is Borel, and $C$ differs from $B$ by a countable set, then $C=B\Delta A$ for some countable $A$; since $A$ is countable, $A$ is Borel, so $C$ is the symmetric difference of two Borel sets and hence is Borel. Isn't this what you're asking?

Comment: @Iconoclast Edited to be more explicit.

Comment: Is it true that if $C \Delta B = A$ then $C = A \Delta B$? I cant seem to figure that out. If true than my question is trivial of course.

Comment: @Iconoclast Yes; we can prove this by proving that $(C\Delta B)\Delta B=C$. To see this, suppose $x\in (C\Delta B)\Delta B$. There are two possibilities. If $x\in B$, then $x$ must *not* be in $(C\Delta B)$. Since $x$ is not in $C\Delta B$, it must be in both $C$ and $B$, or it must be in neither $C$ nor $B$; but since we assumed $x\in B$, we must have $x$ is in $C$ as well. So if $x\in B$, then $x\in C$. The other case is similar.

Comment: if CΔB=A then C=AΔB? ... Yes.  Prove that first.  Use the definition: two sets are equal iff they have the same elements.

Answer (score 0):

To obtain $C$ from $B$, we remove countably many points and add countably many points. Index the set of removed points as $\{r_n\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ and the set of added points $\{s_n\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$. Then
$$
C=B\setminus \{r_n\}_{n=0}^{\infty}\cup \{s_n\}_{n=0}^{\infty}.
$$
Since the Borel $\sigma$ field contains any individual point, this is a countable union/intersection of Borel sets. Thus $C$ is Borel.

Comment: This is a very basic question: is it true that $C-B=\{s_n\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ and $B-C=\{r_n\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$?

Comment: Yes, it is true.